# Package user python dependencies for AWS lambda

Tags: python, packaging

## Question

I have local Python files shared among projects. The directories of them are set in PYTHONPATH.

When deploy a Python lambda package to AWS, I like to copy all these files (besides related AWS SDK packages) into a packaging directory with one command, and zip them up.

```
lib
└── py
    ├── aws
    │   ├── dynamo          <--- In PYTHONPATH
    │   └── ec2             <--- In PYTHONPATH
    ├── common              <--- In PYTHONPATH
    │   └── crypt.py    
    │   └── http.py    
    │   └── log.py    
    └── elasticsearch       <--- In PYTHONPATH
```

What are good ways?

- [Best Practices for Developing on AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/best-practices-for-developing-on-aws-lambda/)

  > Lambda functions require you to package all needed dependencies (or attach a Layer) ... you should bundle your own SDK and pin your functions to a version of the SDK you have tested.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `zappa`.

Start by creating a virtual environment and installing/adding all your dependencies to that environment.

Install `zappa` and configure a few settings. You can then deploy your entire code to Lambda with a single command using `zappa`. You can redeploy as many times you want.

Zappa is an open-source library that makes deployment on Lambda a piece of cake.

Typically, deployment involves packaging the virtual environment as a zip, uploading zip files to an S3 bucket, configuring the Lambda function, and attaching it to the API Gateway.

Zappa does all that behind the scenes. It works well with Flask, Django, and other WSGI frameworks.

You can follow the steps from this Medium article -

https://medium.com/better-programming/a-5-minute-guide-to-python-apis-on-aws-lambda-d359630fe743